# Is the given formula correct?

Tags: integration

My teacher used the given formula to solve a question and to my surprise got a correct answer. SO is this formula correct for all values of a? And does there exist a derivation for this formula?
$$\frac{d}{da}\int_0^af(x) dx = f(a)  $$

Comment: Uhm... I'd say it should be $\dfrac{d}{da}$. Anyways, it's called [fundamental theorem of calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#Formal_statements).

Comment: @G.Sassatelli You are right. With $\frac{d}{dx}$ , the left side is $0$

Comment: To derive the formula look at the definition of differential: $$\frac{d}{da} g(a) = lim_{\delta a \to 0}\frac{1}{\delta a}[g(a+\delta a) - g(a)]$$ and put $g(a) = \int_0^a f(x) \, dx$ so that $g(a+\delta a) - g(a) = \int^{a+\delta a}_a f(x) \, dx \approx f(a) \delta a$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eh, no. In fact it depends on the limits of the integral (search for definite integrals to know more) and the fact that you just used the derivative of the anti-derivative, aka two opposite actions.
Say $\int f(x) dx = F(x)$ for the indefinite integral
and $\int_i^j f(x) dx = F(j) - F(i)$
we know that $\frac{d}{dx}F(x)=f(x)$
so $\frac{d}{di}\int_{0}^{i}f(x)dx = \frac{d}{di}[F(i)-F(0)] = f(i)$ As F(0) is a constant.

~~~ By the tunisian : Hachem

Comment: Can you recheck that 3D plane question?

Comment: I simply didn't know the two answers matched so I deleted my post + I didn't know one other thing.